# Need to write a correct query in Derby

Tags: java, derby

I need to filter data in Java app which get data from Derdy. I created a table in Derby and use this query below which is runnable for MySQL but not for Derby. Can anybody have idea how to make the query compatible with Derby?
With this query I need to press button Search and it gives me resuls in JPanel.

```
Select * FROM fruits where concat (apple, orange, banana) LIKE '%"+ValToSearch+"%';
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: Are `apple`, `orange`, `banana` fields in the table? Or literal string values? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

**Derby supports + for string concatenation.**

> Concatenation
>
> The concatenation operator, ||, concatenates its right operand to the
>   end of its left operand. It operates on a character or bit expression.
>
> Because all built-in data types are implicitly converted to strings,
>   this function can act on all built-in data types.

Use `||` to concatenate strings instead of using `concat` funcation.
For more details [view this](http://dba.fyicenter.com/guide/Derby-Reference-Manual/124_Concatenation_operator.html).

Comment: Thanks! But what wrong with this query?   String searchQuery = "Select * FROM fruits where (|| (apple, orange, banana) LIKE '%"+v1+"%') AND (|| (apple, orange, banana) LIKE '%"+v2+"%') AND ( (tour_type, food, accomodation, name, price) LIKE '%"+v3+"%') AND (|| (apple, orange, banana) LIKE '%"+v2+"%')";

Comment: @NadyaD what you exactly want to achieve? Could you please explain what SQL query you want to form?